# What is the purpose of AnonymousSafeObservable and when/why is it created?

Tags: system.reactive

I'm subscribing to an `Observable` using a `Where` predicate and the `ObservableExtensions.Subscribe(this, Action<T>)` method.

When an exception is thrown in the subscribing `Action` I can see a class called `AnonymousSafeObserver` on the stack, this seems to be responsible for causing the disposal of my underlying `Observable` after the exception in the subscription `Action`.

This is not behaviour I had expected or indeed something I've seen before with other subscriptions, usually the exception has just been passed to the caller of `OnNext` (i.e. the observable).

Under what circumstances is this class/behaviour introduced?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot always rely on their being a path from the exception in the observer all the way back to the `OnNext` call of the subscriber.  Anything that introduces asynchronicity will break that chain (`Delay`, `ObserveOn`, `CombineLatest`, etc).

Anyway, if your observer's `OnNext` handler throws an exception, then Rx assumes your observer's state has been corrupted.  `AnonymousSafeObserver` merely ensures that the observer is unsubscribed from the observable in this case to avoid memory leaks and to avoid continuing to send more events to a corrupted observer which might do more harm than good.  It is a fail fast philosophy.

My understanding is that anytime you subscribe to an observable one of these will get created.    Internal subscriptions made by Rx to observables will not use this class because they've already guaranteed that their internal observer implementations never throw exceptions.  But since they treat outside observers (ie your observers and my observers) as untrusted and so wrap them in one of these objects.